# How to get div to uncollapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Get guys,

The following code works ok when click the div opens but i need it to close back when click the button again

here is the JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function slide(){
document.getElementById("sliding").style.maxHeight = "1000px";
}
</script>
```

here is the css

```
#sliding{
    transition: 0.5s;
    max-height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

and the html

```
 <button onclick ="slide();" class="btn btn-primary">ADD COMMENT</button> 



  <div id = "sliding">
    <p>TEST</p>
    </div>
```

could someone help me out making it to hide back the div when clicked on button again?

thanks a ton in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add state to your dynamically changed html.

There are various approaches. The following code uses the value of the css property `maxHeight` on the div whose visibility is toggled, a property that is changed anyway when turning the text visible.

This is not the cleanest way to do it but will show the principle and keeps changes to the given code minimal:

```js
function slide(){
    if (parseInt(document.getElementById("sliding").style.maxHeight) === 0) {
        document.getElementById("sliding").style.maxHeight = "1000px";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("sliding").style.maxHeight = "0px";
    }
}
```

```css
    #sliding{
     transition: 0.5s;
     max-height: 0px;
     overflow: hidden;
    }
```

```html
     <button onclick ="slide();" class="btn btn-primary">ADD COMMENT</button> 
     <div id = "sliding">
        <p>TEST</p>
     </div>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton mate appreciate your help it works perfect :)

Comment: Can i use it like a link instead of button?

Comment: are you there mate?

Comment: Basically you can. just use `<a href="..." target="_blank">...</a>` instead of `button`.

Answer (score 0):

You could include a check in the function to see what the current maxHeight is and change the state of the maxHeight based on the result.  Something like the following using inequality operators in case you decide to change your maxHeight later on.

```
function slide(){
  elem = document.getElementById("sliding");
  elemHeight = elem.style.maxHeight;
  elemHeight.replace("px", "");

  if (elemHeight > "0") {
    elem.style.maxHeight = "0px";
  }
  else {
    elem.style.maxHeight = "1000px";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use classList.toggle method.

```js
function slide(){  document.getElementById("sliding").classList.toggle('sliding-show')
}
```

```css
#sliding{
    transition: 0.5s;
    max-height: 0px;
    display: none;
}

#sliding.sliding-show {
  display: block;
  max-height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick ="slide()" class="btn btn-primary">ADD COMMENT</button> 



  <div id="sliding">
    <p>TEST</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: thanks, how to remove the button and use as a link?

Comment: change button tag into anchor tag.  <a />